# Can I create an x86 based Android Virtual Device (AVD) on a 64 bit Windows 10? If so how?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-virtual-device

I'm new to using Xamarin 2017 to make an Android app.  My VisualStudio_android-23_arm_phone (Android 6.0 - API 23) AVD runs very slowly, and I get a popup saying,

"Running an x86 based Android Virtual Device (AVD) is 10x faster.  We strongly recommend creating a new AVD."

I have a 64 bit Windows 10 laptop, and I've gotten errors running x86 programs on my laptop in the past.  I don't see a "Virtual Devices" option in the Window tap of Xamarin 2017.

How do you suggest I get the right fast AVD?

Comment: If you got errors with x86 programs, they were hardly due to the fact they are run on Windows x64. Have you downloaded an x86 Android image with the Android SDK Manager?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/android-sdk-emulator/

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the Android SDK Manager GSerg ,and thanks for the link to the guide, Jason.  I haven't yet downloaded a x86 Android image with Android SDK manager.  All this is new to me, so I'll learn about those things and then try.  Thanks again

Comment: 32-bit computers only have a `Program Files (x86)` which means they can only run x86 programs. On the other hand, 64-bit computers have a `Program Files (x86)` and a `Program Files` which means they can run x86 and x64 programs. The only difference will be that the emulator files will be stored in `Program Files (x86)` (and a few minor bugs because it was made for computers that have 32 binary digits operating systems)

Comment: Interesting, thanks for teaching me, John D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Visual Studio, in a Xamarin project, open your Android SDK Tools. If you know where the SDK Tools are in the filesystem, you can also do it that way :) You can also type "Android SDK Manager" in the QuickLaunch bar on the top right.

[image]

Then, make sure you have the Intel Hardware Acceleration Manager (HAXM) installed, which will speed everything up TREMENDOUSLY. The reason it's so much faster is the x86 instruction set is the same as your Intel processor, and also uses Intel's virtualization hardware acceleration, provided by HAXM. The "ARM" device simulators simulate ARM processors, which can't easily be simulated by your PC's or Mac's x86-based processor, so they're horrifically slow.

[image]

Then, when debugging, make sure you only use the x86 device simulators, which you access via the Android Virtual Device Manager, next to the SDK Manager:

[image]

Visual Studio *does* have an Android simulator, but I've found the latest Android simulator much better, and it's officially from Google :)

Remember: ALWAYS test your app on REAL DEVICES. Simulators aren't enough of a test. They're great for development, of course!

Hope that helps!

A few more references:

Xamarin Android Simulator Article: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/android-sdk-emulator/

Xamarin University on Android Player: https://university.xamarin.com/resources/working-with-android-emulators

Intel HAXM: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm

Comment: :) Thank you Auri for your helpful screenshots with circles, explanations, links, and insights.  Thank you also for helping me realize that the Android Emulator Manager is the same thing as the Android Virtual Device Manager.  I'm now getting an error about a missing android.jar for API Level 25, even though I used the SDK to install Level 26 and have an android.jar for level 26.  This is probably my fault since I installed more than just the HAXM since I thought Xamarin recommended additional files.  Once I resolve that issue, I'll check the speed of the simulator. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Installing API Level 25 with the SDK resolved the error message, and the AVD is now much faster.  Thank you Auri!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS 2017 I recommend you to use Visual Studio Android Emulator, it can be installed through VS installer package, it´s faster.

If you instead of this want to install AVD can follow this link, [Configuring Virtual Devices](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/android-sdk-emulator/2-configuration-and-use/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, José.  I have the AVD.  I'm now getting an error about a missing android.jar for API Level 25, even though I used the SDK to install Level 26 and have an android.jar for level 26.  Once I resolve that issue, I'll check the speed.

Comment: Installing API Level 25 with the SDK resolved the error message.

Comment: I'm glad you can program